# How to use checkboxes to make filters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I`m trying to make a filter out of checkboxes. I tried lots of ways with    jQuery and JavaScript, but non of them worked.

**Here is the html file**:

```
 <form class="size-form">
            <input type="checkbox" name="min50" class="cb-hide 50e"> меньши 50.000€ <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="50-100" class="cb-hide 100e"> 50.000€-100.000€ <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="100-150" class="cb-hide 150e"> 100.000€-150.000€ <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="150-200" class="cb-hide 200e"> 150.000€-200.000€ <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="200-300" class="cb-hide 300e"> 200.000€-300.000€ <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="50-100" class="cb-hide over300e">    более 300.000€ <br>
 </form>
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="hot-offer p150 s150-200 beograd ">
      <div class="img-and-price">
          <img class="img" src="img/noimg.png" width="280px" height="220px">
      </div>

      <h4 class="offer-location">grad-opstina-ulica</h4>
      <p class="price">90000€</p>
      <p class="size">90m<sup>2</sup></p>
  </div>

   <div class="hot-offer">
     <div class="img-and-price">
         <img class="img" src="img/noimg.png" width="280px" height="220px">
     </div>

       <h4 class="offer-location">grad-opstina-ulica</h4>
       <p class="price">90000€</p>
       <p class="size">90m<sup>2</sup></p>
  </div>

  <div class="hot-offer">
     <div class="img-and-price">
         <img class="img" src="img/noimg.png" width="280px" height="220px">
     </div>
        <h4 class="offer-location">grad-opstina-ulica</h4>
        <p class="price">90000€</p>
        <p class="size">90m<sup>2</sup></p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

This is the closest i got, but it still doesn`t work as planed. I'm trying to make a filler so when none of the checkboxes are :checked, all of the .hot-offer divs are displayed. But when a specific checkbox is :checked, for example .150e, my html file would only show those divs linked to the box.

**Here is my jQuery script**:

```
$(function () {
    $(".cb-hide").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(".hot-offer").hide();
        } else {
            $(".hot-offer").show();
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    $(".cb-hide").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(".p150-200").show();
        } else {
            $(".p150-200").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: _"my html file would only show those divs linked to the box."_ How are `div` elements linked to `<input type="checkbox">`?

Comment: what is ur question then?

Answer (score 1):

I think this works like you want:

```
$(function () {
    $( 'input:checkbox' ).click( function( e ) {
      var name = $( this ).prop( 'name' );
      var offerClass = '.hot-offer.s' + name ;
      console.log( 'offerClass: ' + offerClass );
      $( '.hot-offer' ).hide();
      if ( $( this ).prop( 'checked' ) === true ){
        $( offerClass ).show();
      }

      var anyChecked = false;
      $( 'input' ).each( function() {
        if ($( this ).prop( 'checked' ) === true ) {
          anyChecked = true;
        }
      });
      if( anyChecked === false ) {
        $( '.hot-offer' ).show();
      }
    });


})();
```

I'm sure it could be more elegant but I'm tired.

Pen here: http://codepen.io/SteveClason/pen/qNdMPR

Comment: Yissss :3 Thats it, what ever it is xD Ty ^^

Comment: I wanted to ask, it`s oke if i want to sort only bi size, put i have 3 sortings. 
Thats what p150 stands for. So how do i add so it sorts by s, by p and bay location. If you know what im trying to ask

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking -- could you clarify what you want to happen when a box is checked? And when multiple boxes are checked? Also, do you have control over the generated html?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting `value` of checkbox to match `id` of div

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-hide" value="offer-1">
<div id="offer-1" class="hot-offer></div>
```

Then use [**`toggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to hide/show

```
$('.cb-hide').change(function(){
    $('#'+ this.value).toggle(this.checked);   
});
```

A boolean passed to `toggle()` tells it whether to hide or show the element(s)

Comment: But, what if I have multiple divs on the same checkbox, I mean, woun they mix up?

Comment: Well the relationships weren't clear in question. Using array in a `data-` attribute that either matches ID's or classes would be an alternative. Use `join()` on array to create the jQuery selector. Update question with some legitimate relationships. Looks like you started by using multiple classes on checkboxes but never got to the `<div>`

Comment: @charlietfl You could simply reject it (as you've already rightfully done) without bringing it up. That's way there's an approval system.

Comment: @AngelPolitis well also worth mentioning that it isn't good etiquette to edit very recent answers unless there are glaring errors. That was the whole point

Comment: Oke, one more question, let`s say I joined them. And I select 2 different checkboxes. How do i make them show only the divs they have incommon?

Comment: @Liondj ok...that starts getting more complex. Will need a master array that is generated by looping all the checked checkboxes and collecting all the values that match each one. Let me think on that a few minutes and will get a solution. Clarifying the absolute filtering criteria in question would help

Comment: Oki, i got the main part... Welp i think. You`re saying that i should make an array of divs that complement a certain checkbox, and than i could use the checkbox to manipulate those arrays. And sry for the trouble im causing. I looked 4 hours for the solution, and gave up on searching

Comment: Just update the specific behavior wanted in question for now. I think I know ... you want what is common to all checked checboxes to show only correct? So each checkbox may have several matches of it;s own?

Comment: Yup, i can send you an example website that has it, that might help

Comment: probably irrelevant if other answer does all that you need

Comment: Actually I would like to know what were you thinking. I dont get the answer abowe, plus there is a minior flaw

Comment: And the flaw is that it doesn't create matches for all checkboxes right?

Comment: Yup, and since i had p150-200 and s150-200 i didn`t notice, how did you?

Comment: I could tell just by looking at the code...try this http://plnkr.co/edit/Ac27HTwzTXKaz23Tsa8I?p=preview

Comment: It doesnt work 4 me :( 
Ahhhhh idk, maybe i fudzed somethin

Comment: My demo doesn't work? What browser? Note that if you use text in the `data-` arrays it needs to be valid json. Use single quotes to wrap array...double quotes on array strings

Comment: I give up, i dunno, im sending you the file
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSxarRtWFX7RVBHam137?p=preview

Comment: sry for the bother, you dont have to look

Comment: oki, my bad, it works, but the divs, are just paragraphs. I mean, in stead of a div says hot-offer 1

Comment: OKe, i found out what the problem was:
$offers.text(function() {
        return this.className
      });
    }
this was the problem, it makes divs return only the name of the clas as content, removing that solves the problem, tysm :3

Comment: right..remove that demoSetUp() function...just there for me to not have to manually create content

Comment: Is that the expected behavior as far as matching checkboxes to offers?

Comment: @charlietfl yeah, only one more question, i sorted checkboxes so i have five checkboxes that filter offers by price, and what if i want to select 2 different checkboxes and mix their content?
I dont know if you got me, and if its a bother never mind. 
tnx again 4 everything

Comment: Depends on what the filtering criteria is for *"mix their content"*.